# Ubuntu14.04 boot error

Tags: boot

I am getting this message, while booting Ubuntu 14.04:

```
Try (hd0.0): FAT32: No ANG1
Try (hd0.1): EXT2: No ang1
Try (hd0.2): Extended:
Try (hd0.3): invalid or null
Try (hd0.4): EXT2:
```

Answer (score 0):

Something seem wrong with your GRUB bootloader. You should try to reinstall it, by following the guide at [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System). You will need to use a LiveCD for this task (you can write it to a USB pendrive).

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if none of your hard disk partition has a boot sequence installed. I would say, boot using a Live USB of Ubuntu and create a backup of everything important and then clean install Ubuntu once again.

Hope this helps. :)