# No ANG1 Error when booting from Ubuntu in a dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, easybcd

I dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04. I used EasyBCD to get to the Grub menu where I could select which OS to load. It was all set up and worked.

Recently, however, I tried to boot it up again and after selecting Ubuntu it says:

```
Try (hd0, 0): FAT32: No ANG1
Try (hd0, 1): NTFS5: No ang1
Try (hd0, 2): NTFS5: No ang1
Try (hd0, 3): Extended:
Try (hd0, 4): NTFS5: No ang1
Try (hd0, 5): Extended:
Try (hd0, 5): EXT2
```

and it won't boot.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Same question but with no accepted answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/631776/ubuntu14-04-boot-error/631782